# Azure Web App for Containers state storage

Tags: azure, containers, azure-web-app-service

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#custom-containers) it's possible to mount a storage device to the /home directory, by setting the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` app setting.

Is it recommended to use this storage mount to store irreplaceble data of my app (for example user content)?

Some sub questions that are a pre-requisite for the question above:

- Will this storage immediately be deleted if I accidantly remove the app setting?
- Can this storage be backed up?

Honestly, it feels a bit dangerous, because I can't manage the underlying storage account by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it recommended to use this storage mount to store irreplaceble data of my app (for example user content)?

You could get the answer from this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NoStorage). You could use the mapped sharing path.

> The absence of this app setting will result in the setting being "true". In other words, if this app setting does not exist in your app, you will see the /home directory mapped to Azure Storage.

According to the blog we could know that if you set WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE true, not add it in the app setting, you could use it normally.

> - Will this storage immediately be deleted if I accidantly remove the app setting?

If you want to use the mapped sharing path /home, I recommand that you don't add the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` in the appsetting. If the appsetting is changed then, the instance will restart.

> - Can this storage be backed up?

Based on my knowledge, it seems that it is hard to get the files back if they are deleted.

> Honestly, it feels a bit dangerous, because I can't manage the underlying storage account by myself.

If you are worry about that, I recommand that you could use that mapped sharing path and also backup the important file with self-owned Azure storage.